# SpringBoot OAuth2 error "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am trying to implement OAuth2 - SpringBoot authentication.

I have configured a path with permitAll(), but even though it is configured, it shows error

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

I am using postman to test and simply trying to fetch all users in DB. When I call, the control is not coming to RestController. I would like to just get the users list and permitAll() is provided.

Can anyone please help ?
I am posting the code below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean
  public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").permitAll().
        antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN").
        anyRequest().authenticated();

  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception{
    builder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select usrnam,usrpwd, case when usrsta='A' then true else false end from chsusrmst where usrnam=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select usrnam,usrtyp from chsusrmst where usrnam=?");
  }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @PostMapping("/user/register")
    public String register(@RequestBody User user) {

        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getUserPassword());
        user.setUserPassword(encodedPassword);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "User created";
    }

    @PostMapping("/admin/findUser")
    public User findUser(@RequestBody User user) {

        return userRepository.findByUserName(user.getUserName());
    }

    @PostMapping("/user/findAllUsers")
    public List<User> findAllUsers() {

        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${jwt.clientId:client}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${jwt.client-secret:secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${jwt.signing-key:123}")
    private String jwtSigningKey;

    @Value("${jwt.accessTokenValidititySeconds:43200}") // 12 hours
    private int accessTokenValiditySeconds;

    @Value("${jwt.authorizedGrantTypes:password,authorization_code,refresh_token}")
    private String[] authorizedGrantTypes;

    @Value("${jwt.refreshTokenValiditySeconds:2592000}") // 30 days
    private int refreshTokenValiditySeconds;

    public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(clientId)
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValiditySeconds)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(authorizedGrantTypes)
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .resourceIds("api");
    }
    

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        return converter;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

   

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer serverSecurityConfigurer) {
        serverSecurityConfigurer.resourceId("api");
    }
}
```

Comment: Without the authorization server and resource server classes, it is working for me. Can you share your github repo ,such that I can set up the whole project locally easily?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your consideration. I found the issue. HttpSecurity configuration was missing in Resource server and it has been resolved by adding below section.

```
http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
```